# EF: Declaring Many-to-Many relationship in attributes

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

Many to many relationships can be declared like this in fluent-API.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Course>()
    .HasMany(t => t.Instructors)
    .WithMany()
```

I would rather if there were certain attributes that could do the same in my domain model.
Are there such attributes somewhere in the framework, or can I make some of my own that can affect EF behavior when it generates the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've assumed your model, try below and see if it works.

```
public class Course
{
    [InverseProperty("Courses")] //add this attribute
    public ICollection<Instructor> Instructors { get; set; }
    //other properties..
}

public class Instructor
{
    [InverseProperty("Instructors")] //add this attribute
    public ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    //other properties..  
}
```

that way you tell entity framework to look for what property to map with in the `Course` model for `Instructor`.

Moreover, you don't even need to define that way. but In case you have more than one property of type `Course` in `Instructor` or vice-versa, you will need to point out correctly which is mapped to what.

Still, using fluent API is much better and scalable and manageable

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any attributes for it. If you declare `ICollection<T>` in each entity, EF will create many to many relationships by convention. See [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/234606/Creating-a-Many-To-Many-Mapping-Using-Code-First).